# Pandas: group dataframe on variables depending on threshold

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe, and I want to group it on some variables `a`, `b`, `c`. If I group the dataset by `a`, and count the number of rows for all levels of `a`, if some level of `a` has fewer rows than some threshold, I do not want to continue grouping on `b` and `c` (**for these levels of `a`**). So, I basically want to stop grouping if some group threshold is reached, but continue grouping for the others.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                 'b':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                 'c':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
                })
df_desired=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 1, 2], 
                         'b':[1, 1, 2, 2], 
                         'c':[1, 2, np.nan, 2],
                         'group_size':[3, 3, 3, 9]
                         })
```

My attempt thus far is not very elegant, so I wanted to see if this could be done in a better way?

```
group_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
grouped = list()
n_threshold = 3
df_list = list()

df_tmp = df.copy()
for g in group_cols:
    print(g)
    grouped.append(g)
    df_grp = df_tmp.groupby(grouped).agg(n_rows=(g, 'size')).reset_index()
    df_lt = df_grp.loc[df_grp.n_rows <= n_threshold, ]
    df_list.append(df_lt)
    df_gt = df_grp.loc[df_grp.n_rows > n_threshold, ]
    df_tmp = pd.merge(df_tmp, df_gt[grouped], on = grouped, how = 'inner')

df_list.append(df_gt)
pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: The logic is not fully clear, can you describe it? Could you also provide an example in which groups potentially have more than 3 rows?

Comment: @mozway Sure! I'll provide an example where groups have more than 3 rows

Comment: @mozway edited the example and also described it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a variant that first aggregates on all columns, then sums the values of the groups with a count lower than the threshold, until all are processed:

```
thresh = 3

cols = list(df)
s = df.value_counts()   # faster than groupby.size

out = []
cols = list(df)
while cols and len(s):
    s = s.groupby(level=cols).sum()
    m = s<thresh
    out.append(s[~m])
    s = s[m]
    cols.pop()
out.append(s)

out = pd.concat([x.reset_index() for x in out])
```

Output:

```
   a  b    c  count
0  1  1  1.0      3
1  1  1  2.0      3
2  2  2  2.0      9
0  1  2  NaN      3
```

Comment: Very nice! So your assumption with `s = df.value_counts()` is that all columns in dataset are supposed to be grouped by, right? **edit**: same with `cols = list(df)`, I guess. I see... I can just modify that!

Comment: Yes, if you prefer you can use your `groupby.agg`, just keep the relevant columns as index and manually define `cols`

Comment: may I ask, what do you mean by keeping the relevant columns as index?

Comment: Oh, I see, nevermind :)