# Pandas: iteratively group dataframe on variables to make it smaller

Tags: pandas, loops, aggregate

This question is related to another question I made:
[Pandas: group dataframe on variables depending on threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77555911/pandas-group-dataframe-on-variables-depending-on-threshold)

I have som data with for example `sales` numbers, and I have some attributes that I want to look at the `sales` numbers for, in order to gain insight into how sales is related to the attributes. Now, for some `combination` of attributes, I don't have enough data, so I need to aggregate. I've been pondering how I should aggregate, top-down, or bottom-up. My suggestion in the previous post was the primer, but the answer I got was the latter. I stuck with this latter approach, but I want to use the output as a "model", where I go down the hierarchy of attributes, to figure out what sales I should expect.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,1, 2,2,2, 2,2], 
                 'b':[1,1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,2], 
                 'c':[1,1,1,1, 3,3,3, 5,5],
                 'd':[2,2,2,2, 9,8,7, 4,3],
                 'sale':[0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,2]
                })
```

Solution (inspired by the question I linked to above):

```
thresh = 3
df['n_rows'] = 1
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df['n_rows'] = 1
s = df.groupby(cols).agg(n_rows=('n_rows', 'sum'), 
                         sale=('sale', 'mean')).reset_index()
out = []
while cols and len(s):
    s = s.groupby(cols).agg(n_rows=('n_rows', 'sum'), 
                         sale=('sale', 'mean')).reset_index()
    m = s['n_rows']<thresh
    out.append(s.loc[~m, ])
    s = s[m]
    cols.pop()
out.append(s)

out = pd.concat([x.reset_index() for x in out])
out
```

[image: out]

The problem is that I can't use this table as a model from left-right / top-down, because there are some rows that will not comply with my `threshold limit`, ref. the last row. If I want to look at the sales for `[a, b, c, d] = [2, 2, 3, 4]` I can choose from the two last rows because of the limitation on `a`, but attribute `b` is `2`, where do I go? The penultimate row contains `2` for `b`, but the ultimate row value for `b` is `NaN`, which also contained `2` - before I deleted the information.

I'm losing information when I'm aggregating this way, so I'm just curious if you guys have any ideas how to proceed? Are there a totally different approach to this? I'm not looking for a finished answer here, just some ideas :)

Comment: At first glance it would appear that a tree might be a more appropriate data structure, then you can follow branches based on `[a, b, c, d]` until you reach the end of the branch (which might be truncated based on your `thresh` criteria)

Comment: Yes, true, but I'm not sure how I will do that, tbh.

Comment: Hi, for the last row, n_rows == 2. Since it is under the threshold (3), how come it appears at all?